# Downloading and selecting a powercfg file to import it with c# and not losing focus on the application after the download

Tags: c#, winforms, directory

So currently I'm trying to download a file form the browser;

```
Process.Start("explorer.exe", "link");
```

Since it's a `cdn.discordapp` link it downloads the file immediately. The following code searches for the download file in the download folder and the desktop.

```
var cmdA = new Process { StartInfo = { FileName = "powercfg" } };
    using (cmdA) //This is here because Process implements IDisposable
    {

        var inputPathA = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "C:\\Users\\god\\Desktop\\1.pow");
```

The rest of the code imports the `powerplan` via `cmd` and sets the `powerplan` as active.

```
//This hides the resulting popup window
cmdA.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
cmdA.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

//Prepare a guid for this new import
var guidStringA = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("d"); //Guid without braces

//Import the new power plan
cmdA.StartInfo.Arguments = $"-import \"{inputPathA}\" {guidStringA}";
cmdA.Start();

//Set the new power plan as active
cmdA.StartInfo.Arguments = $"/setactive {guidStringA}";
cmdA.Start();
```

Issues:

- To download the file, any browser has to be opened.
- The download works but the browser does not close automatically.
- Users download path is unknown.

I want to download the file without having the application lose focus. I also want the browser to close automatically after the download is complete.

Comment: You could set the window as always on top for the duration of the download to keep it from losing focus to the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me.

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
    wc.DownloadFileAsync(
      // Link
      new System.Uri("https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/link.pow"),
      // Path to save
      "C:\\link.pow"
 );
```

Comment: No focus loss on the application, no opened browser + no user folder needed (downloads or desktop etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest *not* using a `Process.Start` command to fire up a browser, but instead create an HttpClient in your C# code that will download your file for you and save it locally. This gives you ultimate control over the file. Once the file has downloaded, you can invoke your `Process.Start` and do whatever you need to with the downloaded file.

There are multiple examples of how to download a file using C#, but here's a quick gist:

```cs
async Task DownloadFile(string url, string localFileName)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    using (var response = await client.GetAsync(url))
    using (var fs = new FileStream(localFileName, FileMode.CreateNew))
    {
        await response.Content.CopyToAsync(fs);
    }

    // Do something with the file you just downloaded
}
```